# Baking Fluid Domain Results of Draining Container Fail Above Final Resolution of 50

Tags: physics, fluid-simulation

I hope to create a fairly realistic scene of water draining out of a container, revealing a moving object within.

All objects have been set up with their normals checked for consistency and scale and rotation normalized with Control-N. The animation is six seconds at 30 frames per second for a total of 180 frames. When I do a test bake at a final resolution of 50 with a simulation start time of 0 and end time of 9 seconds, the container drains at a reasonable rate and I am pleased with the outcome, with the exception of the slip behavior at the fluid/container interface.
[image: Draining container at Final Bake resolution of 50]

[image: Fluid scene]
many particle objects are on layer2 to keep them from appearing in the render
[image: Fluid simulation settings]

When I increase the final resolution to 100 in hopes of getting better slip results, the water initially looks right
[image]
but appears to drain instantly by frame 1, leaving a few fiddly droplets behind for the rest of the frames.
[image]

Is their something wrong with my drain outflow object that would cause its rate to be bake resolution sensitive?

Is their a persistent place to post blend files, so that people in the future might benefit from examining this blend file?

Comment: The fluid is bake resolution dependant.. but it's not clear what happens on frame 1. Once animation finished and starts playing again everything will return back to initial position. For your blend file use [blend-exchange](http://blend-exchange.giantcowfilms.com/) (to keep under 30 mb clear fluid bake cache).

Comment: Thank you Mr Zak. I have posted the 872 Kb blend file here:
[<img src="http://blend-exchange.giantcowfilms.com/embedImage.png?bid=2036" />](http://blend-exchange.giantcowfilms.com/b/2036/)

Comment: Not sure why the resolution matters, but if you move your *fluid* up so that it does not intersect with the *outflow* everything seems to work.

Comment: I tried your idea @Jbergman. A fluid sim at a final resolution of 50 made for an overly dramatic but very cool cavitation and foamy tank slosh fluid simulation as the fluid crashes into the bottom of the container on the first frame. You are right though, re simulating at a resolution of 100 does not yield the fiddly bits and eliminates the cavitation drama.